# How to assign a default type to create an optional type parameter?

Tags: c#, types, parameters, default, option-type

I can work around this, but I am curious why it won't work:

In the same way that you can create an optional parameter with a default value for a routine, such as the one below.....

```
    public void SomeRoutine(string Title = "Missing")
    {
        // Do something with Title
    }
```

.... why can't you assign a default Type as an optional parameter ?

The following example gives the error:  *"Default Parameter For 'theType' must be a compile time constant."*

```
    public void SomeOtherRoutine(Type theType = typeof(MyClass))
    {
        // Do something based on theType
    }
```

The actual application is trying to do provide the option for enumerating a collection that contains a mix of base and various derived classes, and returning only the class type of interest:

```
    public IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> EnumerateWithOptions(Type optionalDerivedClass = typeof(MyBaseClass))
    {
        foreach (MyBaseClass thingy in MyCustomCollection())
        {
            if (thingy.GetType() == optionalDerivedClass)
            { yield return thingy; };
        }
    }
```

The obvious alternative is to overload the routine to apply the default value as shown below, however it is not ideal in my app for reasons that are not worth trying to describe.

```
    public IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> EnumerateWithOptions()
    {
        return EnumerateWithOptions(typeof(MyBaseClass));
    }
    public IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> EnumerateWithOptions(Type optionalDerivedClass)
    {
        foreach (MyBaseClass thingy in MyCustomCollection())
        {
            if (thingy.GetType() == optionalDerivedClass)
            { yield return thingy; };
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why typeof(MyClass) is not considered a compile time constant, or any ideas for a different approach ?  Thanks.

Comment: The compiler is creating the overload for you if you provide a default value.  As such I usually avoid providing default values and use overloaded methods instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  An overload is logistically different from a default value when there are multiple parameters with default values.  The example that I provided doesn't show it, but the application has several parameters in the EnumerateWithOptions routines, each with default values - including enumerate direction, row vs col first scanning, child inclusion, duplicate key iterator, etc.  Trying to express all of the combinations of options as overloads would be too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thus you cannot use `typeof` or some `Type` value, and you don't want to create overload manually, then consider provide `null` as default value for optional parameter:

```
IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> EnumerateWithOptions(Type optionalDerivedClass = null)
{
    if (optionalDerivedClass == null)
        return MyCustomCollection();

    return MyCustomCollection()
        .Where(thingy => thingy.GetType() == optionalDerivedClass);
}
```

If it is possible for you to use generic parameter instead of `Type` object, then you can filter collection via `Enumerable.OfType<T>()`:

```
IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> result = MyCustomCollection().OfType<YourType>();
```

Comment: The use of null is the closest to directly addressing my original question of how to setup a type parameter with a default value.  I am still not sure why typeof(MyClass) is not considered a compile time constant.  Thanks lazyberezovsky, I will mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @user1689175 `typeof()` is not considered as a constant, because it is a method call to `System.Type.GetTypeFromHandle`. And you can't use method calls (which happen only at runtime) to setup constants.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
  public IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> EnumerateWithOptions<T>()
  {
      foreach (MyBaseClass thingy in MyCustomCollection())
      {
         if (thingy.GetType() == typeof(T))
         { yield return thingy; };
      }
  }
```

usage

```
var list = EnumerateWithOptions<MyBaseClass>();
var list = EnumerateWithOptions<MyDerivedClass>();
```

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer my original question of how to specify a type parameter with a default value - I really like this approach and will try implementing it.  Thanks for the great suggestion !!